# Puedo hacer Global Query Filters en Entity Framework 6? en el OnModelCreating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

estoy intentanto hacer esto en EF6. se puede? QUiero hacer un filtro blobal

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<Cotizacion>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.EstaBorrado = false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La caracteristica a la cual haces referencia solo es posible implementarse en `EF Core`

[Filtros de consulta global](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/filters)

Ahora bien, existen extensiones que permiten lograr lo que planteas

[Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/overview)

Si analizas las opciones de esta libreria veras que se incluye

[EF+ Query Filter Global](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-filter#ef-query-filter-global)

Y este es compatible con `Entity framework 6`

La otra alternativa seria ver de trabajar con `interceptors`

[EntityFramework.Filters](https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters)

como veras que lo define al usar la libreria

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   DbInterception.Add(new FilterInterceptor());
}
```

Comment: Gracias, la ultima es la mejor pues la configuracion se hace en el onModelCreating, las demas es lo mismo q hacer los filtros cuando los necesitas en los controles, gracias